# Regex: How to filter javascript code for nested functions

Tags: javascript, regex, rxjs

I'm currently refactoring and I want to find nested subscriptions in my javascript Project.
Im wondering how to do this with regex.

So the bad code could look like this:

```
something$.subscribe(() => {
  // ...
  another$.subscribe(() => {}) // should find .subscribe( here
  // ...
})
```

And I would like to find every `.subscribe` nested inside a `.subscribe(() => { //nested }`

Comment: Please add what you already tried. And think twice if you want to do that with regular expessions. I think you'd need a recursive regex here (`.subscribe() { ... { ...} ...  { .subscribe(` -> find that)

Comment: Well, I have started thinking about it. Of course I could write a script to filter these cases. I was just wondering if it is possible in Regex.

Answer (score 1):

This problem relies on the number of curly braces `{...}` that need to be counted, which means you need a recursive regex. Such recursive regex is not possible in the vast majority of languages and therefore probably not your code editor. If the second `.subscribe(` is not nested in more curly braces, you could search for one curly brace, e.g

```
/\.subscribe\(.*?\{.*?\.subscribe\(/
```

If you would like to only match the last .subscribe:

```
/(?<=\.subscribe\(.*?\{.*?)\.subscribe\(/
```

Note that this will match

```js
something$.subscribe(() => {
  // ...
  another$.subscribe(() => {})
  // ...
})
```

but not

```js
something$.subscribe(() => {
  // ...
  if(...){
    another$.subscribe(() => {})
  }
  // ...
})
```

or

```js
something$.subscribe(() => another$.subscribe(() => {}))
```

Comment: What about code within comments?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Code within comments may also cause the regex to fail. Even though it is possible to eliminate this issue, I don't believe it would be worth it as this solution is not meant to be complete (as I stated, a complete solution would likely be impossible), but rather to catch the majority of cases

Answer (score 0):

```
/\.subscribe\(.*\.subscribe\(/gms
```

works for me

Comment: But this does not respect to only find nested `.subscribe(`. It needs to find only the ones inside the brackets.